# Saving results for query with For xml and query hints into a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @xml_var XML  

SET @xml_var = (SELECT *
                FROM Customers 
                WHERE CustomerID = 'Someone'
                FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
               )
```

This throws a syntax error.

Is there anyway to add the query hints to the SQL? If I remove the `Option optimize`, the assignment works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SELECT instead of SET.

```
DECLARE @xml_var XML  

SELECT @xml_var =  
(
SELECT   *
FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID='Someone'
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE    
)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: Worked! Appreciate your help.